# Pandas dataframe sum of row won't let me use result in equation

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, sum

Anybody wish to help me understand why below code doesn't work?

```
start_date = '1990-01-01'
ticker_list = ['SPY', 'QQQ', 'IWM','GLD']
tickers = yf.download(ticker_list, start=start_date)['Close'].dropna()


ticker_vol_share = (tickers.pct_change().rolling(20).std()) \
                    / ((tickers.pct_change().rolling(20).std()).sum(axis=1))
```

Both `(tickers.pct_change().rolling(20).std())` and `((tickers.pct_change().rolling(20).std()).sum(axis=1))` runs fine by themselves, but when ran together they form a dataframe with thousands of columns all filled with nan

Comment: what's the error message you get? also provide a sample of tickers df data ( as code)

Comment: What are you trying to get?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.

```
rolling_std = tickers.pct_change().rolling(20).std()
ticker_vol_share = rolling_std.apply(lambda row:row/sum(row),axis = 1)
```

You will get
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Why its not working as expected:

- Your `tickers` object is a DataFrame, as is the [`tickers.pct_change()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pct_change.html),  [`tickers.pct_change().rolling(20)`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rolling.html) and [`tickers.pct_change().rolling(20).std()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.std.html). The [`tickers.pct_change().rolling(20).std().sum(axis=1)`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sum.html) is probably a Series.
- You're therefore doing element-wise division of a DataFrame by a Series. [This yields a DataFrame](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.div.html).
- Without seeing your source data, it's hard to say for sure why the output DF is filled with `nan`, but that can certainly happen if some of the things you're dividing by are 0. It might also happen if each series is only one element long after taking the rolling average. It *might* also happen if you're actually evaluating a Series `tickers` rather than a DataFrame, since `Series.sum(axis=1)` doesn't make a whole lot of sense. It is *also* suspicious that your top and bottom portions of the division are *probably* different shapes, since `sum()` collapses an axis.

It's not clear to me what your expected output is, so I'll defer to others or wait for an update before answering that part.

Comment: Thanks for your comment! Sayan dasgupta's  answer did it for me.